# Oracle spatial - check polygon vertices counter clockwise

Tags: oracle, spatial

I need to import a huge number of polygons from a third party (as a csv file- array of x,y's). I have to check whether the polygon vertices are in clockwise or counter clockwise, finally i have to convert it into counter clockwise and store it in the oracle spatial table as sdo geometry.

I am not able to find any oracle spatial java API to check the array of vertices and convert it into counter clockwise. I tried the same question in oracle spatial forum, but they said no API for this.

do you have ever worked on this oracle spatial java API, any other thoughts. ( i have found some methods to validate the ring rotation "http://paulbourke.net/geometry/clockwise/index.html", but if it is from oracle it will be good to implement).

Could you help me in getting the oracle spatial java api,

Answer (score 0):

Knowing NOTHING about the Oracle Spatial Java API, take a look at the `oracle.spatial.topo.CompGeom` class. It has three different methods for computing cross-products. One of those should work for your data.